# Reproduzir video no app ou fora

Tags: android, ios, apache-cordova, app, youtube

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo mobile de serviços & noticias pra uma empresa e neste há uma área de vídeos relacionados a instituição. A duvida é:
 Visando a melhor experiência para o usuário, o app deve reproduzir os vídeos ou solicitar um reprodutor padrão?

Obs.: são vídeos do youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pensando do ponto de vista do usuário, eu preferiria que o video abrisse dentro do aplicativo ao invés do App ser minimizado e abrir o arquivo em um reprodutor externo, pois, sempre tem o detalhe de voltar pro App depois de ver o video, se forem vários videos...

Também tem o lance da performance, qual player pretende utilizar? App nativo ou phonegap?

Links que podem ajudar:

- http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2013/04/12/html5-video-preload/
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

icul8r.

Comment: Esta sendo usado phonegap.

Comment: @Matheus

Dependendo então da quantidade, acho que você deveria utilizar o player do aparelho. No caso, se forem vários videos dai acharia melhor você tentar desenvolver um gridzinho com thumbnails e carregar no click/tap. 

Boa sorte.

Answer (score 0):

Para vídeos hospedados no youtube utilize a biblioteca **Youtube Android Player API** integrado ao seu aplicativo nativo. Bem tranquilo de configurar. Veja mais em:

- https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/